# to extract just the month

Tags: sql, database, oracle, extract

Find the busiest registration month for pet in the past. We assume that the more pets are registered, the busier the month is.

```
SQL> select reg_month, registration
from 
(select to_char(dateRegistered,'dd-mon')reg_month,count(*) registration
from pet
group by to_char(dateRegistered,'dd-mon'))
where registration = (select max(registration)
from (select to_char(dateRegistered,'dd-mon')reg_month,count(*) registration
from pet
group by to_char(dateRegistered,'dd-mon')));



 REG_MONTH  REGISTRATION
 --------------- ------------
 12-nov            3
```

can someone please help me extract just the month instead of day also.

Comment: `to_char(dateRegistered, 'mon')`

Comment: @Gordon Linoff  i tried that one but I'm only getting error.

Comment: Do you really want to group together all the records from, say, November in all years? It's unclear from the first sentence.

Comment: @jojo - what error do you get? Have you changed all four of the appearances of `dd-mon` to `mon`?

Comment: @Alex Poole, yes i changed all four appearances. 
 
                     *
ERROR at line 2:
ORA-00904: "DATEREGISTERD": invalid identifier

Comment: dateregisterd --> dateregisterEd

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Oracle supports Standard SQL's `EXTRACT` and then you can use `RANK`:

```
select *
from
 ( select extract(month from dateRegistered) as mnth, 
      count(*) as cnt,
      rank() over (order by count(*) desc) as rnk
   from pet
   group by extract(month from dateRegistered)
 ) dt
where rnk = 1
```

Comment: is it possible to change 11 to appear in month character like nov, instead of 11. thanks.

Comment: @jojo: Of course, simply use Gordon's proposal: `to_char(dateRegistered,'mon'))`

Comment: thank you, for your help. can you take a look at the error and guide me once. thanks

 select *
from
 ( select to_char(dateRegistered,’mon') as mnth, 
      count(*) as cnt,
      rank() over (order by count(*) desc) as rnk
   from pet
   group by to_char(dateRegistered,’mon')
 ) dt
where rnk = 1 ;
 ( select to_char(dateRegistered,’mon') as mnth,
                                             *
ERROR at line 3:
ORA-00907: missing right parenthesis

Comment: @jojo: There's the astersk in `COUNT(*)`
 missing, otherwise the syntax is correct.